# TestCafe & NIVO Issue

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, nivo-slider

I've a question. Did anyone experience a problem that I've with running TestCafe and hitting NIVO?

All tests that hitting NIVO are failing with the following error message:

```
 A JavaScript error occurred on "https://localhost.dev.[webportal].com:3333/dashboard".
      Repeat test actions in the browser and check the console for errors.
      To ignore client-side JavaScript errors, enable the "--skip-js-errors" CLI option, or set the "skipJsErrors" configuration file
      property to "true".
      If the website only throws this error when you test it with TestCafe, please create a new issue at:
      "https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md".
      JavaScript error details:
      ref.add is not a function
```

[SEE SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2seDr.png)

Answer (score 1):

All updates will be posted to an appropriate [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6341) in the TestCafe repository.